# Python: Interpreter returns Objects/Functions instead of evaluating

Tags: python

I am using python-3.2.3 64bit and I am seeing some strange behavior.

For Example when using the interpreter:
The Input

```
>>> range(10)
```

results in the Output

```
range(0, 10)
```

when it should print

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Simmilary Input

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> f = filter( lambda x: x<2, l)
>>> f
```

leads to Output

```
<filter object at 0x00000000033481D0>
```

but it should be

```
[0, 1]
```

Obviously I cant do anything with that Object:

```
>>>> len(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    len(f)
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Ok, I obviously read the wrong doc, embarrasing. Sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out. Its all clear now.

Answer (score 18):

Nothing is wrong. `range()` is Py3.x yields items 1 at a time like generators unlike its behaviour in Py2.x that was to generate a list right then and there and then return it to you. Wrap your call to `range(10)` in a call to `list()` and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: And the same applies to filter

Comment: Also, I think `f` is still usable as it is, as long as you iterate over it and don't expect it to behave like a list.

Answer (score 3):

Those functions return iterator objects. You can convert them to lists using `list(range(0, 10))` or `list(f)`. You also can iterate through the results like:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(i)
```

Finally, you can use `next` function to get next item:

```
l = range(0, 10)
l1 = next(l)
l2 = next(l)
```

Returning iterators instead of lists allow to perform complex operations on items without having to load all of them into memory. For example, you could iterate through a huge file and convert it character by character, without needing to load the entire file into memory.